# Lowercase first element of tuple in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, text-processing

I have a list of documents, labeled with their appropriate categories:

```
documents = [(list(corpus.words(fileid)), category)
              for category in corpus.categories()
              for fileid in corpus.fileids(category)]
```

which gives me the following list of tuples, where the first element of the tuple is a list of words (tokens of a sentence). For instance:

```
[([u'A', u'pilot', u'investigation', u'of', u'a', u'multidisciplinary', 
u'quality', u'of', u'life', u'intervention', u'for', u'men', u'with', 
u'biochemical', u'recurrence', u'of', u'prostate', u'cancer', u'.'], 
'cancer'), 
([u'A', u'Systematic', u'Review', u'of', u'the', u'Effectiveness', 
u'of', u'Medical', u'Cannabis', u'for', u'Psychiatric', u',', 
u'Movement', u'and', u'Neurodegenerative', u'Disorders', u'.'], 'hd')]
```

I want to apply some text-processing techniques, but I wish to maintain the list of tuples format.

I know that if I had only a list of words, this would do:

```
[w.lower() for w in words]
```

But in this case, **I want to apply .lower() to the first element (list of strings) of every tuple in the tuples list**, and after trying various options like:

```
[[x.lower() for x in element] for element in documents],
[(x.lower(), y) for x,y in documents], or
[x[0].lower() for x in documents]
```

I always get this error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

I have also tried applying what I need before creating the list, but .categories() and .fileids() are properties of corpus and they also return the same error (they're lists as well).

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

**SOLVED:**

both @Adam Smith's answer and @vasia were right:

```
[([s.lower() for s in item[0]], item[1]) for item in documents]
```

@Adam's answer above maintains the tuple structure; @vasia does the trick right from the creation of the list of tuples:

```
documents = [([word.lower() for word in corpus.words(fileid)], category)
              for category in corpus.categories()
              for fileid in corpus.fileids(category)]
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: You need to nest one deeper...

Comment: @yinnonsanders yes it is, I've referred that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so your data structure is `[([str], str)]`. A list of tuples where each tuple is `(list of strings, string)`. It's important to deeply understand what that means before you try to pull data out of it.

That means that `for item in documents` will get you a list of tuples, where `item` is each tuple.

That means that `item[0]` is the list in each tuple.

That means that `for item in documents: for s in item[0]:` will iterate through each string inside that list. Let's try that!

```
[s.lower() for item in documents for s in item[0]]
```

This should give, from your example data:

```
[u'a', u'p', u'i', u'o', u'a', u'm', ...]
```

If you're trying to keep the tuple format, you could do:

```
[([s.lower() for s in item[0]], item[1]) for item in documents]

# or perhaps more readably
[([s.lower() for s in lst], val) for lst, val in documents]
```

Both these statements give:

```
[([u'a', u'p', u'i', u'o', u'a', u'm', ...], 'cancer'), ... ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close. You are looking for a construction like this:

```
[([s.lower() for s in ls], cat) for ls, cat in documents]
```

Which essentially puts these two together:

```
[[x.lower() for x in element] for element in documents],
[(x.lower(), y) for x,y in documents]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
documents = [([word.lower() for word in corpus.words(fileid)], category)
              for category in corpus.categories()
              for fileid in corpus.fileids(category)]
```

Comment: Thank you! This saves me the extra lines of code and does the job in a single step. :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, tuples are immutable. However, since your first element of each tuple is a list, that list *is* mutable, so you can modify its contents without changing the tuple ownership of that list:

```
documents = [(...what you originally posted...) ... etc. ...]

for d in documents:
    # to lowercase all strings in the list
    # trailing '[:]' is important, need to modify list in place using slice
    d[0][:] = [w.lower() for w in d[0]]

    # or to just lower-case the first element of the list (which is what you asked for)
    d[0][0] = d[0][0].lower()
```

You can't just call `lower()` on a string and have it get updated - `lower()` returns a new string. So to modify the string to be the lowercased version, you have to assign over it. This would not be possible if the string were itself a tuple member, but since the string you are modifying is in a list in the tuple, you can modify the list contents without modifying the tuple's ownership of the list.