# Create tuples that have a word of mixed case as the first element and an entirely lowercase string as the second element

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, element

Create tuples that have a word of mixed case as the first element and an entirely lowercase string as the second element. Take a list of space separated words for your input.

this is what i have so far:

```
result = {}
words = ("VaneSSa likES tO RuN")
words1 = words.split()
for dic in words1:
    result[dic] = dic.lower()
print(result)
```

Output:
{'VanEssa': 'vanessa', 'likeS': 'likes', 'tO': 'to', 'Run': 'run'}

I realize this is a dictionary, and the exercise is to have it be a tuple. Here was the example they used:

"For example, if you are given the string:

RADIO aStRoNoMy Pulsar

you need to obtain the following tuple of tuples using a tuple comprehension:

(('RADIO', 'radio'), ('aStRoNoMy', 'astronomy'), ('Pulsar', 'pulsar'))"

I also referenced [Lowercase first element of tuple in list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042431/lowercase-first-element-of-tuple-in-list-of-tuples)

but am having a difficult time understanding how to change this from a dictionary to tupple

Comment: `tuple(dict.items())`

Comment: Why are you even using a dictionary if you don’t need one?

Comment: I originally thought it was a dictionary. I can start from scratch too, I was hoping there would be an easy way to re structure it as a tuple vs dictionary. I'm learning there is no "easy" way unless i want to skip on learning the concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
result = []
words = ("VaneSSa likES tO RuN")
words1 = words.split()
for dic in words1:
    result.append(tuple([dic, dic.lower()]))
result = tuple(result)
```

Comment: You made building the tuple overly complicated. Just `result.append((dic, dic.lower()))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
words = input("Enter words to transform to lowercase here. Separate them with spaces:")
result = tuple((word, word.lower()) for word in words.split())
print(result)
```

Gives you:

```
(("RADIO", "radio"), ("aStRoNoMy", "astronomy"), ("Pulsar", "pulsar"))
```

Comment: Hey, nice answer! Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Answer (score -2):

Dictionaries have a function to get all items as tuples. Use: `tuple(result.items())`

The result of the `items` function is a list of tuples. To have a tuple of tuples instead, I use the `tuple` function for conversion.